# Whenever...then

Tags: grammaticality

In my mathematical writing in grad school there used to be sentences like "*Whenever* x is a fish, *then* x is an animal." (Yes, that's what my dissertation was on!) I am a native speaker of English and this seemed fine to me.

My adviser (who is not a native speaker of English, though it's not entirely relevant) insisted that this was incorrect, so I stopped using it because he was pretty much the only one reading what I wrote. He suggested replacing "then" with "we must have that" (which I did).

I still wonder, though...is it really incorrect?

Comment: I might suggest deleting “then”:  *Whenever X is a fish, X is an animal.*  But why not just: All fish are animals.

Comment: From a programmer's perspective, this sounds the same as saying _while_ x is a fish, _then_ x is an animal.  I prefer _while_ but won't say whether _whenever_ is incorrect or not.

Comment: @Jim Ignore the specific example. However, I just tried to find a more realistic example in my dissertation and discovered that the word "whenever" appears exactly once, and it isn't used in this way, so maybe I just stopped using it.

Comment: I'm hardly a mathematician, but wouldn't "if ... then..." work just as well _and_ be grammatically correct?

Comment: @Ricky Sure it would. But "if ... then..." is used so often that one gets very tired of it. Variation is preferable even in dry stuff like math.

Comment: @Ricky For example, while "whenever" is used once, "if" is used 164 times in my dissertation.

Comment: How about "Should [...] turn out to be [...] then, perhaps,[ ...] might come off as [...]"

Comment: @Ricky Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm not in dire need of a replacement at the moment. The question is just whether what I used to use is correct.

Comment: I believe it is correct, just a bit awkward. "Whenever" mixes better with "it must also be true that" than "then." I must say I've noticed that whenever (no pun intended) you math freaks dig up a problem that isn't related to your own field, everyone's suddenly stumped because a) no one thought of it before b) no one will ever think of it again. (Hey, have any of you figured out yet who killed Kennedy? what's the location of the actual, historical Troy? ...)

Comment: @araucaria mine is likely totally unrelated. "The Leibniz formula for divided difference operators associated to Kac-Moody root systems." There's a link in my profile.

Comment: @MattSamuel Yes, you're right! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... is it really incorrect?

Yes, I think the "whenever X then Y" construct is incorrect. It should be "whenever X, Y", where X is a logical proposition and Y is an assertion (Y could also be a command - e.g. *whenever it rains, take an umbrella*). The expression "then x is an animal" doesn't stand as an assertion or command on its own.

The adviser's expression "we must have that" is just a filler which can be removed in its entirety without changing the sense of the sentence. What it gives you, though, is more visual separation between X and Y than just a comma - this could be important for clarity when X and Y are equations or other expressions that already contain commas.

Comment: That's probably why I felt the need to put something like "then" in. "Whenever x+1=5, x=4" is pretty confusing.

Comment: @MattSamuel Yes - add commas and accidentally skip a conjunction, and it gets worse. E.g. Whenever x=1, y=2, z=3. :)

Comment: But then why have *then* in conditionals at all. This is still a conditional. It just has a different type of subordinator.

Comment: @Araucaria That might deserve its own question. It can be argued that *then* carries the sense of *in that case*. This works when coupled with *if*, but *when* / *whenever* has a slightly different feel (mood?). *In that case* is already built into the semantics of *when* / *whenever*, which makes repeating it sound clumsy.

Comment: @Araucaria Greg Lee observed that *whenever* is a quantifier. Although we may quibble about exactly what the domain is, reading *whenever* as a universal quantifier rather than a conditional expression makes it even clearer that the word *then* is out of place. We can have "for every [event clause], [assertion]" but not "for every [event], then [description]". E.g. "for every x classified as a fish, x is also classified as an animal" (correct) vs "for every x classified as a fish, then x is also classified as an animal" (wrong).

Comment: I think you might have missed the word *implication* in Greg's description. Basically, that bit of the description is what makes it a conditional. The rules about when we can use conditional *then* are complicated, [but they are not based on the form of the sentence](http://web.mit.edu/linguistics/people/faculty/iatridou/natural_language_semantics.pdf). It's perfectly possible to use conditional then with exhaustive conditionals. Indeed OP's *"Whenever {x1, x2, . . . , xn} is a basis of V, then Sym(V) is isomorphic to the polynomial ring F[x1, x2, . . . , xn]"* would appear to be such a case.

Comment: So we can make OP's sentence fine if we give it the right context. For example **It is not the case that whenever something is fish-shaped, it is necessarily an animal. Rather, whenever something actually *is* a fish, *then* it is an animal**

Comment: @Araucaria That's an interesting paper, though in his (1b) "If Pete runs for for President, then the Republicans will lose", the presupposition of the English sentence can even be (in Iatridou's terminology) the stronger O [~p] ~q, particularly when the stress is on the word *then*. His example 69 also directly confirms the assertion in my answer. On Greg's description - the quantification is the new element ...

Comment: @Araucaria ... Also, the OP's example maps more closely to the logic statement *[forall] x [in] fish [.] x [in] animal* than the quantified implication *[forall] x [.] x [in] fish [=>] x [in] animal*, which would be more like "whenever you have an x, if x is a fish, then x is an animal". That last statement is actually matches the semantics / effect of your last example surprisingly well even though the syntax may suggest otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

*He suggested replacing "then" with "we must have that" (which I did).*

It might be a bit late, but can I suggest that you find a new supervisor?

Comment: He's not my adviser anymore. It never really comes up, but my proper title is Dr. Samuel, and his signature is on the title page of the copy of my dissertation stored in the bowels of Rutgers' archives (but the text is accessible online!).

Answer (score 1):

Anyone who knows some predicate logic will be able to tell that with "Whenever x is a fish, then x is an animal." you are trying to get the logical symbols to correspond directly, one-for-one with English phrases.  But it's not really possible to translate in this literal way.  Your former adviser's idea of using "we must have it that" for implication is certainly no improvement.

James McCawley was a first class linguist who also knew quite a lot about logic.  In **The Syntactic Phenomena of English** he makes some very specific proposals about how universally quantified implications correspond to English sentences.  He begins with the restricted quantification discussed by Hans Reichenbach -- (All x: fish(x))(animal(x)), where the implication operator has been suppressed, and applies more or less motivated syntactic rules to get to "All fish are animals".

Is your version with "whenever" really incorrect?  Well, it's pretty bad.  It seems to be making a generalization about all times which is just not there in the logic or in the corresponding English.

Comment: Unfortunately the book costs far more than $8 so I can't justify buying it. In any case, I've only seen sentences like "All fish are animals" on IQ tests, never in math papers. Perhaps I picked a bad example. What can the logic do with  "Whenever {x1, x2, . . . , xn} is a basis of V, then Sym(V) is isomorphic to the polynomial ring F[x1, x2, . . . , xn]"?

Comment: Instead of "whenever", use "if".  The "if" ... "then" construction of English is the most common translation of the material implication of classical logic.  Material implication "p implies q" or "if p then q" is equivalent to "not p or q".  There are other proposals about how to render the "if ... then" construction of English, but mathematicians like material implication because it preserves the validity of modus ponens.  ...

Comment: ... Concerning your example, I see nothing there relevant to our discussion.  Involving some mathematical notions "basis", "isomorphic", "ring" looks to me like a distraction.  What do these have to do with logic or its correspondence to English?  Is it your idea to scare me away by tossing in some mathematics you think I won't understand?  Are you asking a real question?

Comment: No scaring intended, and I didn't think it mattered whether you knew the meanings of the words. I just felt that "all fish are animals" was a form that was special to my contrived example and thought maybe you had some logic to English conversion algorithm in front of you and could do something with this. The sentence is an if...then from my dissertation, but instead I put it in this form.

Comment: Well, in case I wasn't clear earlier, "whenever" is no improvement on "if", since it purports to make a generalization about times.  "When" means "at the time at which".  But a generalization about times does not seem to be involved in any of these examples, so "whenever" is an unwise choice.

Comment: *When(ever)* and *if* are interchangeable when the fact that X occurs is presupposed.

Comment: @GregLee Although *when* is associated with time, in the context of Matt's question it is more closely related to the concept of an *event*. E.g.: "when it rains, use an umbrella" - time is incidental; the *rain* event is central. It follows that *whenever* is a quantifier for events, not times. Matt's example sentence, while ungrammatical, does make sense from this perspective. That is, it is more natural to read his intent as "For each fish instantiation of x, ..." rather than "At the times x is a fish ...".

Comment: @Lawrence Exactly so.

Comment: @Lawrence, So you're saying "x is a fish" is an event??  Or "{x1, x2, . . . , xn} is a basis of V" is an event??  This makes no sense.

Comment: @GregLee Yes, it is interpreting the 'P is a Q' form as having P vary (Q may also vary), occasionally satisfying the proposition 'P is a Q'. Those occasions are the events.

Comment: But @Lawrence, that's not true.  You're just making it up.  The semantics of predicate logic has been well-studied, as it applies to mathematics, throughout the 20th century.  Logic and mathematics are not about events that take place at times.  You can use logic and maths as tools to describe events, but that is not the subject matter of these disciplines.

Comment: @GregLee I studied formal logic extensively, but my comment in this case wasn't about formal logic. It was about English words in a particular form - e.g. "x is a fish" is in the form "P is a Q" where P=x and Q=fish. My previous comments were about the assumption leading to your conclusion that '"whenever" is an unwise choice', that assumption being that '"When" means "at the time of which"'. My use of the word "event" is in the sense of an "occurrence".